# Magento 2: GraphQL V/S REST API

Tags: magento2, api, json, graphql

I am planning to build API's.

Which is better GraphQl or REST API?

How easy to customize either as per the developer perspective view?

https://www.howtographql.com/basics/1-graphql-is-the-better-rest/